# problem regarding iphone Web App

Tags: iphone

I need to create a web app on iphone. How to go about it?

Comment: Will you please provide some detail ?

Comment: What investigation have you done so far, perhaps via Google or the Apple site..?

Comment: Please explore more about your requirement  . 
Here is one way to use web related page with your app:
You need to create html file and keep inside resource/ plist. Now you can read it with appropriate  path and redirect this path inside webview.

Comment: Thanks sudesh, however i have already done that, i want to know what other methods are there to do that...

Comment: @Raxit I am starting to work on a web app, for that i have to study abt it and i am going through all the tutorials but still have some doubts abt how to start and how to use webkit and all ??

Comment: can u provide me with a sample project?

Comment: @Neha Madhup he provided you good link you can find more detail from that link. I would like to work using Objective C Language.  Titanium is good if you want to develop application using html and javascript

Answer (score 1):

there you are: http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/

A search on Google for 'Webapp Tutorial' can do magical things.

**Edit:**

This one for HTML5

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **[Wink Toolkit](http://www.winktoolkit.org)**. Very useful for developing Mobile WebApps.